# How to troubleshoot "System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): File does not exist"?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, httpexception

*Apologies if this has already been answered on this site, I searched but did not find this exact scenario.*

I'm adding log4net to a WCF service. I added a handler in the Application_Error event, and it is catching a file not found error on every request.

I've seen this with web sites, and usually the error can be traced down to not having a "favicon" file in the root directory, or to a missing image referenced in a css stylesheet.

However, this is a WCF service, there is no CSS stylesheet, and adding a favicon to the root did not solve the problem.

Does anyone else have a good way to troubleshoot this?

Some clues:

- I haven't deployed this yet to the real IIS server, I'm running it locally.
- The error does not happen when I am running in DEBUG inside Visual Studio, only when I access the service from a web browser (IE or Chrome)
- I added the url and file path to the error message, and this is what they are:

  **URL:** http://localhost:3994/

  **FilePath:** /

  **Error:** System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): File does not exist.

Edit: the above values are what show up in the logged exception:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    if (objErr is System.Web.HttpException)
    {
        var filePath = Context.Request.FilePath;
        var url = ((HttpApplication) sender).Context.Request.Url;
        Log.Error("URL: " + url + "; FilePath: " + filePath, objErr);
    } else
        Log.Error("Application Error", objErr);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget to mention .svc file in URL?

Comment: See the edit I posted to my question.

Comment: use the ` key (the one that contains the ~ character as well) to format code in comments and the like.

Comment: @Joel, not all keyboards have the back-tick on the same key as the tilde.  On mine, `, ¬ and ¦ are all on the one key :)

Comment: @Drew Noakes - truly, but as in most things in life, the percentages are high that OP is using a Dvorak qwerty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is likely that the service has not been specified.  When a web server (the local dev one as well) recieve a request for a folder they look inside that folder for the default page (usually called: index.htm, index.html, default.asp, default.aspx, etc) and present that (unless you are using a REST based service description).  When you run from VS the debug will take you straight to the actual service.

In this case because you have built a service you need to specify the location of the exact service i.e. `http://localhost:3994/service.svc`.

Also: If you start a debug session and then change the URL to `http://localhost:3994/` you should be able to check this is the case with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to understand why this is happening. I suppose it shouldn't happen too often in a production environment, so I will just add some logic to trap for it and not worry too much about it.

Comment: Better yet, add a static html page as the default that tells the user nothing about what is at that site just who/where to contact.  Then you don't have to worry about handing the error as you usually wouldn't log a 404 (not found) error anyway.